# how to share Azure mobile service tokens across different web app instances

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, access-token

I am planning to have multiple azure mobile service instances, so the first requirement I have is to share the access token of authenticated user across different app instances. I found this article https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/ that states that right now we can not share the tokens as it is stored locally on machine, and placing it to blob storage is not recommended for production apps. What is the possible solution I have at this time?

Answer (score 0):

I have read the [blog](https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/) you mentioned about App Service Token Store. As mentioned about where the tokens live:

> Internally, all these tokens are stored in your app’s local file storage under **D:/home/data/.auth/tokens**. The tokens themselves are all encrypted in user-specific .json files using app-specific encryption keys and cryptographically signed as per best practice.

> I found this article https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/ that states that right now we can not share the tokens as it is stored locally on machine.

As [Azure-runtime-environment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment) states about the **Persisted files** that an Azure Web App can deal with:

> They are **rooted in d:\home**, which can also be found using the %HOME% environment variable.
>
> These files are persistent, meaning that you can rely on them staying there until you do something to change them. Also, they are **shared between all instances of your site (when you scale it up to multiple instances)**. Internally, the way this works is that they are stored in Azure Storage instead of living on the local file system.

Moreover, Azure app service would enable **ARR Affinity** to keep a client subsequent requests talking to the same instance. You could disable the session affinity cookie, then requests would be distributed across all the instances. For more details, you could refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/05/16/disable-session-affinity-cookie-arr-cookie-for-azure-web-apps/).

Additionally, I have tried to disable **ARR Affinity** and scale my mobile service to multiple instances, then I could always browser  https://[my-website].azurewebsites.net/.auth/me to retrieve information about the current logged-in user.

Per my understanding, you could accomplish the authentication/authorization by yourself to use auth middle-ware into your app. But, this requires more works to be done. Since the platform takes care of it for you, I assume that you could leverage Easy Auth and Token Store and scale your mobile service to multiple instances without worrying about anything.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, In above question, where I mentioned multiple instances, I mean multiple azure mobile service instances across different region e.g. One in Asia, one in Europe and another one in US, and use azure traffic manager to direct the request to nearest instance, so if a user from India tries to call my api and it gets redirected to Europe instance (e.g. when I am updating the server in asia region), since its token is stored locally on Asia server, and when the request goes to Europe server, it will decline the request

Comment: Based on your latest scenario, if you worry about the instance is not accessible when you update the server, you could leverage [deployment slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing)  to set up development environment and validate app changes in a staging deployment slot before swapping it with the production slot.

Comment: Or you need to build your auth service into your app and store the user logged-in information (e.g. provider, access_token, etc.) into a shared storage (e.g. [Azure Redis Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache)) for a higher performance. Additionally, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services).

Comment: The Azure Storage is common to all scale units within a region.  Thus, if you have two regions - one in West US and one in East US, then you have two Azure storage accounts and two token caches.  ARR Affinity will ensure your users are always hitting the right/same regional service.

Comment: Thanks Bruce and Adrian. I don't think it solves my problem. Suppose that I first added my app in US region, so folks from Asia and Europe will still be using the app, so they would be connecting to US Region, and after sometime if my user base grows in Asia and Europe, I will deploy the app to Asia and Europe region, and Azure Traffic manager will divert them to App near to their location, since their tokens are stored on my US region machine, they will get authentication error. What I am getting is If you are using Azure Mobile Service, Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT, Authenitcation was the only reason I used Azure mobile services, I am using Document DB which is not supported by Azure mobile service, offline support is only for SQL. If I have to implement my own custom authentication, I will scrap the Azure Mobile service, and would be very disappointed